# How to register Dependencies by Names in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I'm using unity to implement Dependency Injection in my .NET Web Api app.
 Here is the relevent part of my WebApiCongig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            var container = new UnityContainer();
            AppDependancyRegistry.Register(container);
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

        }
    }
```

And here is my AppDependancyRegistry class

```
 public static class AppDependancyRegistry
        {
            public static void Register(UnityContainer container)
            {
                    container.RegisterType(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
                    //container.RegisterTypes( AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),  WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);

            }
        }
```

I have mapped the Generic Repositores but I couldnt get through with  registering the Manager classes to its interfaces. I dont want to map every one of Manager classes Manaually.

I have commented the part I have done from all the research. I just want a confirmation, this is how I do it as I cant get my App running now without doing some more of stuff

My manager classes:interfaces looks like

```
DutyManager: IDutyManager
UserDetailManager:IUserDetailManager
```

etc. Thanks in Advance

Comment: *I dont want to map every one of Manager classes Manaually* - why not?

Comment: More work.. is bad. is my concept. Learn for once is good

Comment: You can bulk register all implementations of a single interface, but not multiple interfaces is my understanding. At least in castle, ninject, structuremap, and tinyioc. I've not used unity.

Comment: Your posted code looks ok -- what's the issue?

Comment: @tomredfern actually u can using unity. just the commented line in my code will do. I  got it workign

Comment: @RandyLevy. Yeah. It works..Thanks. But I did not hav a good idea it would work as I was doing it first time. Also My app was not in a buildable condition too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this qn. Using Unity we can directly Map all classes to respecive Interfaces by using

```
container.RegisterTypes( AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),  WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);
```

Here, Unity maps by convention where they map like this

```
DutyManager: IDutyManager
UserDetailManager:IUserDetailManager
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need, at some point, to register each of them. However, if you don't want to manually do each and every one of them, what you could "basically" do is, by reflection, load the assembly, iterate over every interface, check how many classes implement that interface, if there is only one, register the interface to that class as an unnamed registration.

Why unnamed? Well, named registration are useless unless you actually use the name in the registration, or in the `ResolvedParameter` constructor, and since you're not "hand crafting" the registrations, you wouldn't refer to them most likely.

Don't forget though that in your case, since the interface and the classes are generics, you'll need to check the `ParameterType` too.